# Connect register user control to SQL Server database in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server

I'm really sorry, might be this is really primary level question, but I'm new to asp.net and I searched a lot, but couldn't find proper solution for my question.

My question is: I want to save my user registration data into a SQL Server database and within create user button I wrote following code:

```
protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   UserDTO user = new UserDTO();
   user.userName = RegisterUser.UserName;
   user.password = RegisterUser.Password;
   user.userType = "User";

   string continueUrl = RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl;

   if (user.addUser())
   {
       continueUrl = "~/";
   }

   Response.Redirect(continueUrl);
}
```

Within `addUser()` I create a connection and try to save them. But I found within the project there's a built-in database called `App_Data`. So even data does not save to my SQL Server database, in second time it says user name is already there. So that means my user name is saved in `App_Data` database.

**My question is:**

1. How can I remove this `App_Data` ?
2. Can I look into this `App_Data` table structure?
3. or any suggestions to use this user control to save data into a SQL Server database?

**EDIT :**
my Config file as follows:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="DatabaseFactoryConfiguration" type="PatientMgt_DataLayer.DatabaseFactorySectionHandler, PatientMgt_DataLayer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MyConnection1" providerName="MSSQL" connectionString="Data Source=pqr;Initial Catalog=HospitalMgt;User Id=sa;Password=abc" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <DatabaseFactoryConfiguration Name="PatientMgt_DataLayer.MsSqlDatabase" ConnectionStringName="MyConnection1"/>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MyConnection1" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MyConnection1"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />

      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Error I received -

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Default Membership Provider could not be found.

**Edited Question**

problem is when user add user name and pwd via that form and if data does not save to the db why does form do not allow to add same user name again?

Comment: Please provide the code for `addUser`. That'll make diagnosing it easier.

Comment: See my updated post - you need to define a default on your `<membership>` node - like this:  `<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">`

Comment: @marc_s i changed it that way...  but still gives same error. edited question as you sugested

Comment: Well, you need to use **YOUR** name for the membership provider! You've called it `MyConnection1` (right here: `<add name="MyConnection1" ....` - that's the **provider name** that you define, and that's the name you must use as your default provider! `<membership defaultProvider="myConnection1">`

Comment: @marc_s - thanx now that connection problem is solved. next problem is when user add user name and pwd via that form and if data does not save to the db why does form do not allow to add same user name again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, a few things:

- `App_Data` is a well-known ASP.NET **folder** - not a database.
- By default, the ASP.NET membership provider will place it's SQL Server Express `ASPNETDB.MDF` data file into that folder, and use it from there

So you don't need to remove `App_Data` or anything like that - you just need to tell the ASP.NET membership system to use your own SQL Server database.

To have the ASP.NET membership tables in your own database, you need to:

1. execute the `aspnet_regsql` utility, found in your .NET folder (typically something like `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\` or whatever version of the .NET framework you're using); run that app, you'll get a dialog to guide you through the installation of the ASP.NET membership stuff into your own database.
2. then you need to modify your `web.config` to make sure the ASP.NET membership system uses **your database** and not it's default SQL Server Express.

You probably have something like this in your web.config when you've created a standard ASP.NET application:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" 
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
   <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
         <clear />
         <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
              type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
              connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
              enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
              requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
              maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
              minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
              applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
   </membership>
```

And most likely, you already have some connection string of your own, for your own database - right?

So you just need to change the ASP.NET `<membership>` tag to use **your** connection string!

```
<system.web>
   <membership>
      <providers>
         <clear />
         <add name="PutYourDefaultDatabaseConnectionStringNameHere"  <<=== CHANGE THIS!
              type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
              ....... />
      </providers>
   </membership>
```

Comment: in here PutYourDefaultDatabaseConnectionStringNameHere -> according to ur example do i need to put ApplicationServices?

Comment: i have edited my question. i attached my web.config file information

Comment: i ran aspnet_regsql and configure it to sql server. then change as u suggested( updateed my question) but it give above error.